# how to install kde connect on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, kde, android

kde connect is a new app aims to connect android phone and ubuntu/kubuntu and having lots of features. 
the steps involved in installing this piece of software in ubuntu 12.04 is shown in this official link http://larsemil.se/small-howto-on-kde-connect-and-ubuntu/ i am getting a lot of error which i am not able to rectify so please help me out i am dying to use this thing as samsung kies is only supported in windows even though android is a inux based product.sorry for my poor english

Comment: i have upgraded to ubuntu 14.04 but i am not able to find kde connect in programs or by searching in dash. and on running in terminal nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

This is now packaged as an indicator for 14.04, named [`kdeconnect`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kdeconnect).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vikoadi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kdeconnect indicator-kdeconnect
```

http://vikoadi.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/kde-connect-indicator.html

Comment: I am not too sure why add-apt is needed? isn't indicator-kdeconnect being arbitrarily suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kde-connect
```

Answer (score 0):

Kubuntu 13.10 repositories contain kde-connect package. So,

```
sudo apt-get install kde-connect
```

should do the job

Comment: but i am using ubuntu 12.04 and even though it's not working